# Knowing that data from an NSStream is complete

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdata, nsstream, transmission

I'am sending chunks of `UIImage` data over `MCSession` with an `NSStream`.

When I get bytes

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {

   if (eventCode == NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable) {

      // read data and append to self.data
      // how to know that self.data can be used to create UIImage

   }

}
```

I append them to a mutable data instance. The problem is how to know that the accumulated data represents a full image, so I can use `-[UIImage initWithData:]` to create it?

Answer (score 1):

You should watch for `NSStreamEventEndEncountered`

Comment: the NSStreamEventEndEncountered is useful only when the stream was finished, which is not the case (in that case an stream = 1 image, in this case stream = n images)... or is it better to use 1 stream per image?

Comment: having one stream per image is definitely one way of doing that yes :)

Comment: @Lance but how would you know when to open an InputStream to get that one image? Perhaps one-image-one-stream is ok for sender: you want to send image -> you open a stream -> write chunks -> close stream. But how would the receiver handle incoming images if there are several of them?

Answer (score 1):

The stream has no knowledge of its contents. If you can't rely on the stream ending to tell you that the data is complete, then you either need to use/create some protocol for the transmission that includes a "finished" signal, or just try to create the image and take appropriate action if that fails.

Comment: what is an appropriate 'finished' signal?

Comment: Depends on your application. You'd have to come up with some kind of packet format, with a header for each chunk you send.

Comment: now iam starting to get the right track, i could reserve the last 4 bytes of the buffer for 0 / 1 which would indicate a complete object was send... do you thing its better to do it this way, or to have a stream per image?

Comment: Writing your own transmission protocol seems likely to get complex quickly. I'd suggest leveraging the stream's existing functionality as far as you can, and yes, letting one stream carry one image.

Comment: @JoshCaswell but how would you know when to open an InputStream to get that one image? Perhaps one-image-one-stream is ok for sender: you want to send image -> you open a stream -> write chunks -> close stream. But how would the receiver handle incoming images if there are several of them sent over several streams? I'm new to streams.